# classic ASP with non-english languages special characters as boxes

Tags: character-encoding, asp-classic

I am currently working on Classic ASP for one of my project. For non English languages I am getting boxes instead of special characters. I am rendering using UTF-8 but sometimes the characters goes to boxes. It comes back normal when I click refresh sometimes.

I followed all the steps below but i still get this problem

1. XML:

   ```
   <xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
   ```
2. HTML:

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
   ```
3. `content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

Am I missing anything here? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "the steps below"? You didn't post any steps - only bits of text that are not in any sort of context.

Comment: i followed steops mentioned in  below link http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=3bd12e81-2633-45df-b7da-3840c0e8bde7#commentstart    sorry  i was not able to format here prperly

Comment: Is the file encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: The UTF-8 meta tag must be before ALL OTHER meta tags. Put it right after </title>

Comment: @vinod:  To include code in your question paste the code as-is from you source, select it and click the "{ }" button in the toolbar

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your page:

```
Response.CodePage = 65001    
Response.CharSet = "utf-8"
```

It should display all correctly now.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

It's amazing BUT nobody gives a complete answer on what to do this PROPERLY... I hope this help somebody like me, because it was so hard to find the whole picture...

---------------- PREVIOUS CONSIDERATIONS --------------

FIRST, make sure IIS IS NOT replacing the Code Page... Go to IIS, click the Website, open ASP module, on Behavior it should be >> Code Page = 0

SECOND, The file itself should be checked, YES! the file... open your file explorer on windows (my computer), go to the folder where the files of your website are, take for example "default.asp", right click >> open with >> notepad THEN click on File >> Save As... IN THE DIALOG at the bottom says "Encoding", make sure it has UTF-8, otherwise you will have to add the 
`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` in every page (including server side includes), which is not correct.

---------------- CORRECT STRUCTURE OF THE PAGE --------------

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%><%
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=utf-8" 
%><!-- #include virtual="/conexion.asp" -->
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
áéíóú
</body>
</html>
```

It should work fine now with QueryStrings, Database and regular HTML... uffff